# Nested Inner Classes creation in an apex class

Tags: apex, compile-error, inner-class

Below is the structure am trying to build.

Its throwing Error:

> Compile Error: unexpected token: 'class'

```
public class maincls {    
    public class test1 {
        public String teststr {get; set;}
        public test2 testDetails {get; set;}

        public class test2 {        
            public String firstName {get; set;}
            public String lastName{get; set;}
        }
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything here?

Comment: You can only have one inner class. An inner class cannot contain another inner class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have to read the first paragraph of the `Apex Developer Guide` documentation on [Apex Class Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm) to answer this question (emphasis mine):

> ## [Apex Class Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm)
>
> In Apex, you can define top-level classes (also called outer classes) as well as inner classes, that is, a class defined within another class. **You can only have inner classes one level deep.** For example:
>
> ```
> public class myOuterClass {
>    // Additional myOuterClass code here
>    class myInnerClass {
>      // myInnerClass code here
>    }
> }
> ```

So pull out `test2` to nest it only one level deep:

```
public class TopLevel
{
    public class Inner1
    {
        public String someProperty { get; set; }
        public Inner2 otherProperty { get; set; }
    }
    public class Inner2
    {
        public String firstName { get; set; }
        public String lastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```